# Html form tag does not go to the address in action

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form tag that has the action to run a specific .php file with a specific value on the link(mn=2).

```
<form action="http://localhost/UniversityView/index.php?mn=2">
    <button type="submit" name="newrow" class="btn">New Row</button>
</form>
```

I am expecting to go to the pointed link, instead it goes to the landing page which is http://localhost/UniversityView/index.php

What should i do to go the pointed link when the button is clicked?

Comment: Both link are same

Comment: there is ?mn=2 at the end

Comment: they are basically same . You are just making a get request in the same URL with `?mn=2` this at the end